# Json Data couldn't read using flutter_bloc

Tags: bloc

Helo i couldn't show data in UI cause i don't know what steps i skipped with bloc, i thought the step is clear, i'm only using simple function to fetch API but data keep won't show in UI, let see my code below:

> Bloc

```
class ListnotesBloc extends Bloc<ListnotesEvent, ListnotesState> {
  Future<Either<String, Notes>> fetchData() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse('http://108.136.46.147:5000/notes'));

      log('ini isi notes ${Notes.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))}');

      return Right(Notes.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)));
    } catch (e) {
      return Left('err');
    }
  }

  ListnotesBloc() : super(ListnotesInitial()) {
    on<DataShow>((event, emit) async {
      emit(LoadList());
      var data = await fetchData();
      data.fold((l) => log(l), (r) {
        emit(ListHasData(r));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

> UI

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ListnotesBloc _bloc = ListnotesBloc();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _bloc.add(DataShow());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => ListnotesBloc(),
      child:
          BlocBuilder<ListnotesBloc, ListnotesState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ListHasData) {
          log("Ini data diUI${state.notes}");
          return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(state.notes.data);
                },
              ),
              body: Text(state.notes.toString()));
        } else if (state is LoadList)
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        else
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No data'),
            ),
          );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

any step forgot using bloc? any something wrong??

[Pict errorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLZkl.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change the UI to reference the right instance of `ListnotesBloc`.
2. You need to add the `DataShow` event when the `ListnotesBloc` is created, to fetch the data.

Like this:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => ListnotesBloc()..add(DataShow()),
      child:
          BlocBuilder<ListnotesBloc, ListnotesState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ListHasData) {
          log("Ini data diUI${state.notes}");
          return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(state.notes.data);
                },
              ),
              body: Text(state.notes.toString()));
        } else if (state is LoadList)
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        else
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No data'),
            ),
          );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```